# The sum of areas of triangles omitted infinitely many times within an equilateral triangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, geometric-series

[image]ABC

Triangle $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle. Four  new equilateral triangles are  formed by joining the midpoints of the sides $A, B, C$ in $\triangle ABC$ Triangle, with the white triangle in İmage 1, and it is taken out.

Each triangle now formed in $\triangle ABC$ has an area of $\frac 14$ of the area of $\triangle ABC$, as seen in Image 1.

The same process of joining the midpoints in each triangle and taking out the newly formed white triangles is repeated infinitely many times as exemplified in Image 2 and Image 3.

If $\triangle ABC$ has an area of $1\, m^2,\,$ what is the sum of the areas of white triangles taken out?

I know the answer, which I've posted below.

Comment: Did you mean to ask a question that you need help answering?  If you are looking for answers other than the the answer you have to the question, please say so in your original post.  Otherwise, there appears to be no question here that needs answering.

Comment: I found this question in a textbook and believe there may be people who are interested in it, especially since the answer of the question seems wrong at first glance.

Comment: The thing is, Onur.  The purpose of this site is not that it be used as a "public service broadcast".  The purpose of this site is not to post questions you can already answer, along with an answer, just because you think everyone will gain from reading, first your question, then your answer.  Actually, that's rather .... ah, ...  um....so as not to be mean, let's say that it seems you think quite highly of your abilities....for good, or bad.

Answer (score 2):

Every iteration the green area is reduced by 25%.
As the iteration number tends toward infinity, the green area will approach 0.
Since the white area is everything else, its area will tend toward the original area (1).

Comment: Reminds me of the Menger Sponge, the same idea done on a cube. The volume is zero but the surface area is infinite. (!)

Comment: Right... The total boundary length here goes to infinity  :-)

Comment: Its a bit like the surface area of all your capillaries.  I believe this is the equivalent of ~3 tennis courts since the vessels continue to subdivide smaller and smaller until they are just bigger than a red blood cell.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} S &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a\cdot r^{n-1}\\ \\ & = \frac{1}4+\frac{3}{16}+\frac{9}{64}+\dots \\ \\ 
                         &= \frac{1}4\cdot\frac{3}{4}^{0}+\frac{1}4\cdot\frac{3}{4}^{1}+\frac{1}4\cdot\frac{3}{4}^{2}+\dots \\ \\ \end{align}$$

$$ a=\frac{1}4, r=\frac{3}4\implies S=  1  $$